# How do I determine stereochemistry of the product

Tags: reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

When pure (L) lactic acid is esterified by racemic-2 butanol then what is the nature of the stereoisomers so obtained i.e. whether they are diastereomers or enantiomers.

I studied the mechanism of esterification but I didn't find anything regarding the stereo isomerism that can affect the formation of the product.Any ideas.Thanks.[image]

Comment: You can start by identifying all stereocenters in reactants and products. You should assume the reactants are racemic so you will get all combinations in the product.

Comment: @Zhe in the question it is given that a racemic mixture of 2 butanol is used as the reactant but I do not get how it might affect the resulting stoichiometry of the product.thanks.

Comment: @aniline  You are correct, esterification will not affect the stereocenters.  So keeping in mind that the stereocenters are preserved, what products result?

Comment: @ron Yes that would mean that L configuration would remain unchanged and two products with different configuration on other chiral carbon would result in diastereomers.

Comment: @aniline  Nice going!

Comment: The only complication that is not conveyed in this question is that there may be some level of diastereoselectivity. It's probably not very high given these reagents, but for extreme cases, you might be missing one diastereomer altogether because it's so much easy to make the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reaction doesn't change the stereo configuration for either reactant, so we can assume that the product is enantiomerically pure with respect to the carbon attached to the hydroxyl group (in orange below), and a racemic mixture with respect to the tertiary carbon (in blue).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since there are multiple stereocenters, you can either have both the same (same molecule), both different (enantiomers), or have some different and some the same (diastereomer).  The products would be diastereomers.  In particular they would be [epimers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimer), which differ in only one stereocenter.